# What does "fundamental tenants" mean? (not occupant)

Tags: meaning

In the following [sentence](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html), I'm guessing "tenants" means "design goals" (based on the context):

> One of the fundamental **tenants** of Log4j 2 is to use immutable objects whenever possible and to lock at the lowest granularity possible.

I'm not familiar with this usage of "tenants" (there's probably another meaning I'm unaware of) versus this [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tenant):

> **tenant** [ˈtɛnənt]:
>
> *n.*
>
> 1. One that pays rent to use or occupy land, a building, or other property owned by another.
> 2. A dweller in a place; an occupant.
> 3. *Law* One who holds or possesses lands, tenements, or sometimes personal property by any kind of title.

I guessed that it was a typo, but searches for "tennant", "tenent", and "tennent" yielded no results. Can someone please provide the definition (and/or a link)?

Comment: I find these misunderstandings humerus.  I mean...  :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're probably looking for ***tenet***.

> *noun*
>   a principle or belief, especially one of the main principles of a religion or philosophy
>
> [[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tenet)]

Comment: Thank you. I filed a documentation [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-182).

Comment: Makes you wish it was wikipedia, then you could just fix it.

Comment: It's a reasonably common eggcorn: http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/300/tenant/